# How to get result of select query for parameterized stored procedure into a single file using Jmeter

Tags: stored-procedures, jmeter, performance-testing

I am having the query.

1. I am having a stored procedure.I want to run it using Jmeter with parameterization.

   ```
   {call ssp_Devx_ClientInvoiceNewTabReport (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
   //Till here I am able to do it.
   ```
2. Now I want to fire one select query after parameterization.

**Query**

```
    SELECT TOP 1 d.object_id, d.database_id,OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) 'proc name',
    d.cached_time,d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,
    (d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count)/1000 AS[avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time/1000 as last_elapsed_time,d.execution_count,
    *FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d Where
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id)='ssp_Devx_ClientInvoiceNewTabReport' 
    Order by d.Last_Execution_Time DESC
    // For this I added this as another JDBC request.
```

3. The Select query gives me lots of records.I want to fetch few records like `last_elapsed_time`, "total_worker_time" for each set of parameterized data and the entire result I want to save into a single file.
4. I have added file listeners and graph listeners but for each parameterized dataset, they are giving result in a different file and with all result which is returned by a select query.

**Question:**

1. Is there any way that I can make sure that select request is being fired after each parameterized dataset.
2. Is there any way that I can store select query result for each parameter into a file.

Any help/guess/links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `An example of iterating the result set using Beanshell PostProcessor` stanza of the [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide.

It should give you an idea regarding how JDBC Request results look like and how you can work with them